# How to mutate shared value from similar and dissimilar variables using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, data-cleaning

Was having an oddly difficult time trying to find the answer to this probably much answered question, but here is my query. Suppose I have a data frame like the one below:

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(30,40,-999,40,20),
           money.usd = c(-999,55,55,54,30),
           cars = c(1,1,2,0,-999))
```

Filtering and mutating the values are straight forward for single variables. For example, with an `ifelse` statement, I can turn the -999 in age to NA in the following way:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(age = ifelse(age == -999,"NA",age))
```

However, since all of these variables have this value and have different names, I was curious how I can achieve this sort of mutation across several variables. Additionally, if there is the case of many similar variables and many dissimilar variables, I imagine the case is more complicated but certainly ways to make it easier. For example, if I have the following data with three variables for "car":

```
df.2 <- data.frame(age = c(30,40,-999,40,20),
           money.usd = c(-999,55,55,54,30),
           cars.1 = c(1,1,2,0,-999),
           cars.2 = c(0,1,-999,0,0),
           cars.3 = c(-999,5,4,5,4))
```

How would one mutate the value for both `age` and `money.usd` while also selecting several variables of `car` in order to mutate the -999 value? To summarize, my main objective is switching this -999 value from across the data frame to a NA value.

Comment: First of all, you should not quote `NA` in `ifelse(age == -999, "NA", age)`. It'll convert the `age` to a character column. The correct usage is `ifelse(age == -999, NA, age)`.

Comment: Ah thanks for noting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::na_if` to replace a value by NA, and `across` to apply it to multiple columns.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df.2 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ na_if(.x, -999)))
```

If not NA, use `replace`:

```r
df.2 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(.x, .x == -999, NA)))
```

```r
  age money.usd cars.1 cars.2 cars.3
1  30        NA      1      0     NA
2  40        55      1      1      5
3  NA        55      2     NA      4
4  40        54      0      0      5
5  20        30     NA      0      4
```

Or in base R:

```r
df.2[df.2 == -999] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems easy to do this in base R based off your answer, but what if you wanted to mutate the value to something other than NA using the tidyverse?

Comment: Use `replace`, and you can replace NA by anything you want

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton and I'll accept your answer once the time limit is over.